# Visual C++ Runtime on Network Location

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, msvcrt, network-share, matlab-compiler

I have a MATLAB executable that I am trying to deploy within my company, but I don't want people to need to install a bunch of stuff. The executable is saved to a network location and I want them to just run it. I have MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) set up on the network, but now I'm running into issues with Visual C++ Runtime (VC++R) saying the application isn't installed properly. Is there a way to install VC++R to a network location. (People don't have permissions to install things, which is why I want to get away from having to install MCR and VC++R.)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with deployed MATLAB using MCR through r2013a, MCR must always be installed locally.

This does present an issue with thin clients.

A workaround would be to deploy the executable as a remote-ly accessible service, either a Windows Service or other endpoint. This was my solution